# Calculating a limit around a differentiable point

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Here is the question:

With the knowledge that $f$ has derivative in point $a$ and $k>h>0$, show that this limit does not necessarily exist:
\begin{align*}
lim_{k,h \rightarrow 0^+} \frac{f(a+k) - f(a+h)}{k-h}
\end{align*}

Up until this point I tried functions like $f(x) = e^x$ and polynomial functions. which only made me more suspicious about the correctness of problem. Though my closest try was $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ at point $0$ which almost works but fails to be differentiable at point $0$. I have also tried to approach $k,h$ in a special way for example the substitution $h = k^n$ for sufficiently large $n$ makes things a little easier but at the end I failed to find a definite answer.

Now I dont know if the claim is true or not (it may not be and the limit may always exist) but if so, a nice counter would be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: And what contributions do you have to bring to the table, keeping in mind that this site is not a "do my homework for me" absent any and all contributions from the asker.

Comment: @amWhy you are correct. though since the problem is about finding a counter example, I didnt see fit to start talking about what I have done for the problem. but here you go: I added some of my contributions to the problem

Comment: @amWhy btw. Im supposed to solve these problems for some of the freshmen at my university. but the problem set was given to me rather late! and the solution given for the problem is incorrect.

Comment: Dana, thanks for your effort!.